# Display local users using PHP

Tags: php

I am developing a PHP website. My requirement is that when a visitor/user visits my website ; ie, on the home/index page I would like to list all registered users who belong to the same location as the website visitor's. For example if the visitor is from a city X in Kolkata, then list all other registered users from X. How can I implement this feature? Is there any PHP function or like that to find the geolocation. I tried HTML5 geolocation. But it didn't worked?

Comment: This depends on such information that you collected during user registration.

Comment: but we need the current location of the user who may be not registered in the website.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't here to write the code for you. The community will help you get a solution to the problem but at least show us some code that you've tried yourself.

Comment: This a a simple task comprised of two steps: find a user's geolocation and store it, run a proximity search on all stored users. Both parts have been answered many times individually.

Comment: I tried using HTML5 geolocation. But it failed.

Comment: Then try harder. Or ask a specific question about what didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can not be solved exactly in common case. Algorithm is that: use [geoip](http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolocation_landing) database and client's IP-address to get approximate location. Then, using same geoip-database, select similar IP ranges and, finally, search through other users using selected IP ranges. But remember, that users in most cases are behind NAT's, so this solution will be approximate. But you can ask your users when they are registering - about their location. The method I've described before can be used either for registered and unregistered visitors.

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? Seen the scarcity of information from the OP this is as good an answer as he'll get...

Comment: "IP ranges" will be pretty pointless. You need to translate IP address to geocoordinates and run a proximity search on the coordinates, not the IP addresses. If that's what you meant it's not very clear.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. That will be wild-search using, for example, square (long./lat.). In result there should be something comparable with other visitors IP addresses, may be 'range' is not a good word.

Answer (score 0):

Using any geolocation API will be most efficient for this requirement.